# Is possible to change Console window title bar icon using C#?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# console application icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170383/c-sharp-console-application-icon)

I want to change the Console window  title bar icon,

when I run my console application in `c#`.

I have already tried to change the title bar title using `console.title` properties this code.

but I didn't know how to change that icon.

how can I resolve that?

Comment: check it out, i think this is what you asking ??
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170383/c-sharp-console-application-icon

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170383/c-sharp-console-application-icon/1170393#1170393

Comment: What happened to **Google** ?? This is a duplicate question...

Comment: Not possible. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170383/c-sharp-console-application-icon