# add icon to C# console

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console, icons

I am creating a console application and I would like to add an icon for it.
I obviously googled it and came across the exact same answer:
1) Click on the solution
2) Go to Properties
3) Go to application
4) Choose your icon
However when I do this it says ********\icon.ico is not a valid icon file.
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?
By the way I am using Visual Studio.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170383/c-sharp-console-application-icon check this please.

Comment: thanks sorry, didn't see that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you making the icon? The file format is probably incorrect, why not install one of the many free icon makers or try selecting another icon that you know is in a good format to see if the error message goes away.

You can not simply rename a png to ico for example, you need to convert it.

Comment: Why post your comment as an answer?