# how to set console application icon programmatically in c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, console-application

I'm new to C# & got requirement like

> need to change the default console application icon programmatically
>   [also is it possible to change during compile time].

I tried with Project -> Properties -> Application -> Icon of my solution in Visual Studio & its working fine.

Also able to set Form icon with the following code

> this.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(@"Icon.png");

but the thing is i need to change the icon via code.

Help me out.

Comment: With a lot of messing about

Comment: What happens when you run this code `this.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(@"Icon.png");`?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya and what exactly would "this" be in a console app? The startup is a static function. Anyway, flagged as dupe; the question TheGeneral linked has the answer, for console apps.

Comment: @TheGeneral, i tried with that too but no luck.

Comment: @saravana are you trying to change the icon on the console window, or on a form launched from a console app? Because that last piece you put there _is_ programming code you can execute at any moment to change the form icon.

Comment: @Nyerguds I need to change the icon of the console window

Answer (score 0):

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1170393/4977870) which written by **Jon Skeet**

> You can't specify an executable's icon in code - it's part of the
>   binary file itself.
>
> From the command line, you'd use `/win32icon:<file>` if that's any
>   help, but you can't specify it within the code of the application.
>   Don't forget that most of the time the application's icon is
>   displayed, your app isn't running at all!
>
> That's assuming you mean the icon for the file itself in explorer. If
>   you mean the icon of the application *while it's running* if you just
>   double-click the file, I believe that will always just be the icon for
>   the console itself.

Comment: That is about the _file_ icon. This is about the _window_ icon of the console.