# Add Custom Icon to C# Console Application

Tags: c#, console

My Idea is that each user should be able to change the program icon at will through settings, is this possible on the C# Console?

I haven't tried anything yet and I have no idea what I might try

Comment: Hello, @GiorgiAnakidze and thanks for your answer. i want that everyone who uses my program can choose her own icon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably need some configuration file stored at `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local` which is the standard location, from where you will read the icon file path which user has set or the default one if the user didn't change it. For code solution [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170383/c-sharp-console-application-icon). However, if you want to use this application not only on Windows, as far as I'm concerned it's not possible to set icon on a console application on Linux/MacOS.